# rails pass variable from model to another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a rails project and i want to pass a variable from my User model to another controller.

How do i do that? I know it is not the best way to do it but I cant think of any other way to solve my issue.

I am using Devise for my login and I want to display a link if the sign_in fails due to user being locked.

In my User model, i have this method

```
def after_database_authentication
  update_attributes!(password_changed_at: self.last_activity_at)
  user_locked = self.is_locked
end
```

I want to add this variable `user_locked` in my Post controller.

so in my Post controller method new, i want to use it here

```
def new 
  ap user_locked
end
```

Felt the only way i could this was using sessions but cannot assign sessions variable in rails model.

Any other options will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: is `user_locked` a db column?

Comment: no it is not a db column

Answer (score 1):

As you use Devise, the helper method current_user is available for you. So why don't you use such solution?

```
class User
  def locked?
    is_locked
  end
end

UserController
  def new
    current_user.locked?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting confused with the [`MVC`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) structure.

Your `model` is a class which is either populated with database data, or has pre-defined data in the form of *class* methods / variables.

Thus, when you ask....

> i want to pass a variable from my User model to another controller

... the context is completely incorrect.

---

## Model

If you want to pass a *value* through your model, you'll either store it in the database (so one of the model's attributes is populated with the value), or you'll store it as a value at the class level:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   def is_locked?
      true #-> User.new.is_locked? -> true
   end

   def self.is_locked?
      false #-> User.is_locked? -> false
   end
end
```

From what you've written, I would *strongly* recommend making `is_locked` a database attribute:

```
$ rails g migration AddIsLockedToUsers

# db/migrate/add_is_locked_to_users________.rb
class AddIsLockedToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      add_column :users, :is_locked, :boolean, default: false
   end
end

$ rake db:migrate
```

This will set the `is_locked?` value as an *attribute* of your `User` model, which means that each time you call a `User`, you'll be able to check whether they are locked or not:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @user = User.find params[:user_id]
      redirect_to root_path if @user.is_locked?
   end
end
```

--

On top of this, you may wish to use an `ActiveRecord::Observer` or an `after_update` callback to update the locked status:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   after_update :set_locked, if: "password_changed_at.changed?"

   private

   def set_locked
      self.is_locked = true
   end
end
```

Comment: i am not actually confused and this has nthg to do wt the is_locked attribute. maybe i didnt explain clearly.. i hv to show a link on my sign_in page. d link can only b shown if the login failed. d only way to knw if user login failed on my view which is sessions/new is to check if user.is_locked is true or not. But since on sessions/new i dont hv any current_user, d only way to check this is dring authentication save a global sessions variable in model tht i can check on sessions/new to show my link. I hope this makes it a little bit more clearer.